# A clinical test incorrectly identified 50/150 false positives and 23/150 false negatives.Calculate the number of true positives and true negatives

Tags: self-study, clinical-trials

Was wondering if anybody could explain how I can calculate the answer. Would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: not false means true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is self study, I will just offer a hint:

There are four possibilities:

True positive

False positive

True negative

False negative

You have been given two of these and you have also been given two marginal totals. You can then calculate the other two numbers.

It may help to make a table

```
                 ACTUAL
                     Pos           Neg   Total
        Pos     
TEST
        Neg

        Total
```

and then start filling in numbers

Comment: Thanks i'm giving it try now, I feel that it should be really basic I just can't get my head around it, i'll keep you updated!

Comment: The diagram really simplied things, thanks so much! So I got 100 true negatives and 127 true positives. Am i on to something here? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you are on to something.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your help it's much appriceated. Gonna do a few more examples with your table formula !